# openFrameworks for iOS become Apple mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, openframeworks

When I build an example project in openFrameworks for iOS, it becomes `Apple mach-O Linker Error` though I do not do anything to the project.
Whichever sample project I choose, it will be the same result.
How do I fix it?

The followings is whole error message.

---

```
Ld /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emptyExample-ghwshtlvcvsjalcvfnqzpyjfmhhc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/emptyExample.app/emptyExample normal i386
    cd /Applications/of_v0.8.4_ios_release/examples/ios/emptyExample
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=3.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emptyExample-ghwshtlvcvsjalcvfnqzpyjfmhhc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emptyExample-ghwshtlvcvsjalcvfnqzpyjfmhhc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emptyExample-ghwshtlvcvsjalcvfnqzpyjfmhhc/Build/Intermediates/emptyExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/emptyExample.build/Objects-normal/i386/emptyExample.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC ../../../libs/FreeImage/lib/osx/freeimage.a ../../../libs/freetype/lib/ios/freetype.a ../../../libs/FreeImage/lib/ios/freeimage.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoNet.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoNetSSL.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoCrypto.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoXML.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoZip.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoUtil.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/ios/PocoFoundation.a ../../../libs/tess2/lib/ios/tess2.a ../../../libs/glu/lib/ios/glu.a ../../../libs/glu/lib/ios/glu-ios.a ../../../libs/openssl/lib/ios/ssl.a ../../../libs/openssl/lib/ios/crypto.a -stdlib=libstdc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=3.1 -framework CoreVideo /Applications/of_v0.8.4_ios_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/ios/libofxiOS_iphonesimulator_Debug.a -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenAL -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework MapKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emptyExample-ghwshtlvcvsjalcvfnqzpyjfmhhc/Build/Intermediates/emptyExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/emptyExample.build/Objects-normal/i386/emptyExample_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/teruyakusumoto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emptyExample-ghwshtlvcvsjalcvfnqzpyjfmhhc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/emptyExample.app/emptyExample

ld: -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole error that the linker gives into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the 2nd to last line in the error message indicates, it looks like you need to set your "Deployment target" to iOS 4.2 or later. It looks you're trying to build for iOS 3.1, but a library is using API's that require 4.2 or newer.